# Python Regular Expression to find the last occurrence of whitespace in a certain pattern

Tags: python

I am using Regular expression in Python. I want to find the string before last occurrence of whitespace in a certain pattern. For example In the following text, I want to find "Street".
"On Monday , a worker at a [LOC Te Rapa Tika Street ]".

Can anyone help me to find the string using regular expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Split the string on spaces and get the second last element:

```
>>> strs = "On Monday , a worker at a [LOC Te Rapa Tika Street ]"
>>> strs.split()[-2]
'Street'
```

Comment: Actually the string continues with some more text.Also the I want to find the last string inside that pattern [LOC.....]. It may come several time like with different text. Look at this example

Comment: "A man strolling through the [LOC Pullman Hotel ] in [LOC Waterloo Quadrant ] on Sunday with the bag across his shoulder. I want to find "Hotel","Quadrant". Thanks

Comment: something like this then: `re.findall('(\w+)\s]',your_string)`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>  import re
>>>  match = re.search('\[\s?LOC.+\s(\w+)\s?\]', "[LOC Te Rapa Tika Street ]")
>>>  match.group(1)
'Street'
```

This should work regardless of the spacing on the brackets.

Edit: After reading your comment, this would work better

```
   >>>  import re
   >>>  sentence = "A man strolling through the [LOC Pullman Hotel ] in [LOC Waterloo Quadrant ] on Sunday with the bag across his shoulder"
   >>>  match = re.findall('\[\s?LOC[^\]]+\s(\w+)\s?\]', sentence)
   >>>  match
   ['Hotel', 'Quadrant']
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.split` by `\s+` and take the second last token in the returned list (e.g. using index `-2`).

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split